# Index/Match multiple columns in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-match

I have 2 sheets. Sheet 1 is set up similarly to:

```
Keyword  Domain  Rank
  A        Z      1
  B        Z      2
  C        Z      3
  D        Y      10
  E        Y      15
  B        Y      20
```

And sheet 2 is set up like:

```
Keyword  (Domain Z)  (Domain Y)
  A           1          -
  B           2          20
  C           3          -
  D           -          10
```

I'm trying to have a formula that will compare the keywords in Sheet 2 with those in Sheet 1 and then return the rank that corresponds to the correct domain (that's specified in Sheet 2 for that column). I can't get any formula I use to evaluate. I've used 2 formulas so far:

```
=INDEX(Raw!$H$11:$H$322, MATCH(A3,IF(Raw!$D$11:$D$322=All!$B$2,Raw!$B$11:$B$322),0))
```

The above formula works, to a point. The problem is that it simple pulls the domain for the first instance of the keyword found, which doesn't always match the domain in the column of sheet 2. The second formula I've tried:

```
=INDEX(Raw!$H$11:$H$322, MATCH(B3,MATCH($C$2,Raw!$D$11:$D$322,0)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the values appear in the Sheet 2 table, use the following formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($A$2:$A$7=E2),--($B$2:$B$7=$F$1),$C$2:$C$7)
```

[image]

This returns `0` for non-matches - you can either format the cells to display 0 how you want, or you can use the longer/uglier:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--($A$2:$A$7=E2),--($B$2:$B$7=$G$1),$C$2:$C$7)<>0,SUMPRODUCT(--($A$2:$A$7=E2),--($B$2:$B$7=$G$1),$C$2:$C$7),"-")
```

---

To calculate the rank on the first sheet based on the data from the second sheet:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,$F$2:$H$5,MATCH(B2,$G$1:$H$1,0)+1,FALSE)
```

For sample purposes, this just put your sheet2 data in F1:H5. 
[image]

This looks for the corresponding keyword and then uses match to pick the right column. I named the columns `Z` and `Y`, but if you need `Domain` included that can be done as well. Note that this causes an error since there is no `E` defined in your second table - is that the case? If so, it can be adjusted to account for no matches as follows (assuming Excel 2007):

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A6,$F$2:$H$5,MATCH(B6,$G$1:$H$1,0)+1,FALSE),"Rank Not Found")
```

[image]

Comment: I've tried both your formulas. Everything I'm getting is #REF ("or the error if I use your 2nd formula). I stepped through the formula and everything evaluates up until the VLOOKUP. At that point it fails. My knowledge of Excel isn't enough to know why.

I did modify your formula a bit to make it fit my sheets. I'll also add that in your example, Columns G and H I want to be replaced with the formula. I simple put numbers in there to show what I want. I'm not sure if VLOOKUP works here (again, could be wrong) because the columns it's looking at is not sorted in any order and is words w/ spaces

Comment: Gotcha - so you want the formulas to be in columns G and H, basically saying "For keyword A, find the corresponding rank for domain Z"? The #REF is basically just saying that you are referring to an invalid reference, which happens easily when try to port a formula from one place to another :) Does it work if you set it up just like the example above? I'll amend the answer to handle your actual case.

Comment: To your question, that's exactly what I'm looking to do. It does work if I set it up like your example.

Comment: Cool deal - I added that to the top of the answer - let me know if that works for you!

Answer (score 0):

You could also use PivotTable with Keywords in rows and Domain names in columns. It seems like that would do the job and be a more robust solution.